# Paperclip image name changed after updating any attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

This is my model

```
class Technology < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name #etc ....
    has_attached_file :logo, :path => ":rails_root/public/technologies/logos/:normalized_input_file_name"

  Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_input_file_name do |attachment, style|
      attachment.instance.normalized_input_file_name
  end

  def normalized_input_file_name
      name = "#{self.name}".downcase
      "#{self.tuid}_"+name.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}/,' ').strip.gsub(/\W/,'_').gsub(/\A_/,'').gsub(/_\z/,'')+"_150x"+".png"
  end
end
```

When I create any technology, I upload a logo for it and the image stored in public directory with the new name as I want using the method "normalized_input_file_name".
e.g.technology name is HTML5 and file name becomes id_html5_150x.png
But when I need to update name the image path also changed.
e.g. HTML 5 file name becomes id_html_5_150x.png Here actual image file name is not updated
But path is updated. So I can't find the image.

Comment: why do you want such synchronisation between name and logo? these are 2 different attributes

Comment: For SEO purpose. HTML5 logo can be named as xyz.But as per conversions  It is good if I keep image file as technology name

Comment: why don;t you have a helper which adapts the alt attribute of the pic?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `before_save` hook to download and store the image again if you recognize that the `name` attribute going to change.

This code is totally untested but should give you an idea:

```
before_save do
  if self.name_changed?
     self.logo = logo.uploaded_file
  end
end
```